# When updating from Flutter 2.x to 3.x, why previously working <T extends Class> is not working properly anymore?

Tags: flutter, dart-null-safety

When updating from Flutter 2.x to 3.x, I noticed the most difference now is the null sound safety. So I updated my library. At the moment, I stumbled upon this issue:

Flutter 2.x:

```
class GenericJsonObject {

  // ... various variables and methods

  GenericJsonObject wrap(dynamic json) {
    if (json == null) return null;
    var obj = GenericJsonObject();
    obj.something = json.decode();
    return obj;
  }
}

class PersistentData<T extends GenericJsonObject> {

  String key;
  T function() itemCreator;

  PersistentData({ @required this.itemCreator, @required this.key });

  Future<T> get getData async => itemCreator().wrap(AsyncStorage.readMap(key));

}
```

This is working on Flutter 2.x.

But now after I update it to Flutter 3.x:

```
class GenericJsonObject {

  // ... various variables and methods

  GenericJsonObject? wrap(dynamic json) {
    if (json == null) return null;
    var obj = GenericJsonObject();
    obj.something = json.decode();
    return obj;
  }
}

class PersistentData<T extends GenericJsonObject> {

  late String key;
  late T function() itemCreator;

  PersistentData({ @required this.itemCreator, @required this.key });

  Future<T?> get getData async => itemCreator().wrap(AsyncStorage.readMap(key)); 
  // this is error

  Future<GenericJsonObject?> get getData2 async => itemCreator().wrap(AsyncStorage.readMap(key)); 
  // this works, but I don't want this
}
```

The error is:

```
A value of `GenericJsonObject?` can't be returned from the 
function `get` because it has a return type of `Future<T?>`.
```

Why is this happening? Why don't `T?` (where `T` is is defined as generic type extension of `GenericJsonObject`), can't hold value of `GenericJsonObject?`?

I also have tried to make the definition to `<T extends GenericJsonObject?>` and change the return value into `Future<T>` but it also produce similar error.

This works on Flutter 2.x, so it makes me confused why it doesn't work on Flutter 3.x. How can I fix this and make this work?

Answer (score 0):

This because when you pass T extends GenericJsonObject, it mean that you pass it 's child, example when you have a subclass :

```
class GenericJsonObjectChild extends GenericJsonObject {}
```

then this happen:

```
PersistentData<GenericJsonObjectChild>().getData 
// this will return GenericJsonObjectChild

wrap 
// this will return GenericJsonObject
```

So error occur, to fix this you must sure T is excatly GenericJsonObject, then you could change

```
  Future<T?> get getData async => itemCreator().wrap(AsyncStorage.readMap(key)) as T;
```

Comment: So, I only can pass the children, but I can't pass the parent specified on the `extends` itself? I'm curious why it works on 2.x, but doesn't work on 3.x?

Answer (score 0):

For now, the solution I need is actually just to add typecasting.

```
Future<T?> get getData async => itemCreator().wrap(AsyncStorage.readMap(key)) as T;
```

After I add the `as T`, the error disappears and the app can be compiled successfully. I'm not sure whether there won't be any repercussion, but that's currently the only solution working for me.